# Get value of secrets using a variable name in GitHub Actions

Tags: bash, shell, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am creating a re-usable workflow that will have a `secrets: inherit` directive.

Therefore it will inherit the secrets from the invoking workflow.

I want to build a convention where some secrets will be named according to the `Dockerfile`. So for example if the dockerfile is named `Dockerfile` the convention is that these secrets will be stored in a secret variable named `Dockerfile_BUILD_SECRETS`

However the following shell step fails

```
      - name: get build secrets
        shell: bash
        run: |
          SECRETS_NAME="${{ inputs.dockerfile }}_BUILD_SECRETS"
          BUILD_SECRETS="${{ secrets.${SECRETS_NAME} }}"
          echo "BUILD_SECRETS=$BUILD_SECRETS" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

with the error:

```
Unexpected symbol: '${SECRETS_NAME}'. Located at position 9 within expression: secrets.${SECRETS_NAME}
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I'm not well-versed in github actions, but AFIK `${{ .... }}` would require a github variable inside, like `secrets.foo`. How about `${{ secrets }}.$SECRETS_NAME`? But even then, I could imagine that `SECETS_NAME` should be defined in an `env:` section.

Answer (score 1):

You can access secrets via `secrets[secret_name]`

```
    - name: get build secrets
      env:
        SECRET_NAME: ${{ inputs.dockerfile }}_BUILD_SECRETS
      run: |
        echo "SECRET_NAME = $SECRET_NAME"
        echo "SECRET_NAME = ${{ env.SECRET_NAME }}"
        BUILD_SECRETS =${{ secrets[env.SECRET_NAME] }}
        echo "BUILD_SECRETS = $BUILD_SECRETS"
```